# Internet connection on guest when the host has wifi connection and the router allows only the mac address of the host (virtual machine)

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine

My question is: Can I have internet connection on the guest machine, when the host has wifi connection and the router allows only the mac address of the host to connect with it? How does it called in networking terminology, when your mac address is only allowed to connect with the rooter?

Comment: The virtualbox should see your computer as the default gateway to the internet. If the computer has router access, then the vm does because the vm piggybacks off of the computer's internet connection without appearing in the router's view. Basically, the computer passes the vm's network traffic as it's own to avoid small things like that. In other words, use NAT mode, as @David Dai recommended.

Answer (score 1):

NAT network mode should work OK.